# Python defaultdict object's attribute raises AttributeError

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have Python 2.7 code that uses `defaultdict` to create a dictionary `mydict` that creates default objects of `MyClass`, as shown below.

My understanding is that if the key `foo` does not exist in the defaultdict, then a new object of `MyClass` would be created, and since I have an `__init__()` method, then the attribute `value` would also exist. So why doesn't the code below work, where I have:

```
print mydict['foo'].value # Raises AttributeError
```

However, this code *does* work:

```
mydict['foo'].value = 1 # Works fine
```

What's the correct approach to solve the error? (I'm a C++/Java programmer, by the way.)

Below is the entirety of the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

mydict = defaultdict(lambda: MyClass)
print mydict['foo'].value # Raises AttributeError
#mydict['foo'].value += 1 # Raises AttributeError
#mydict['foo'].value = 1 # Works fine
```

The result:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-c9dd776d73de> in <module>()
      6 
      7 mydict = defaultdict(lambda: MyClass)
----> 8 print mydict['foo'].value # Raises AttributeError
      9 #mydict['foo'].value += 1 # Raises AttributeError
     10 #mydict['foo'].value = 1 # Works fine

AttributeError: type object 'MyClass' has no attribute 'value'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify `defaultdict(lambda: MyClass)`, what the default dict produces is the `MyClass` definition (through the lambda) which does not have `value` as it is not defined in the class, as that is what is being returned with that particular construct (default dict will invoke the first argument that it was constructed with if it was a callable object, and you can see this yourself already in the exception message you have included in your question).  See this example:

```
>>> MyClass.value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'MyClass' has no attribute 'value'
>>> mydict['foo'].value = 1
>>> MyClass.value
1
```

If you truly want to return the raw class, provide that value attribute like so (but it will be shared across all default values)

```
class MyClass(object):
    value = None
```

Or do what you really want, which is to provide a default instance of the class, which you can call that manually in the lambda, or reduce it to simply:

```
mydict = defaultdict(MyClass)
```

Comment: Thank you. What's the difference between the two declarations `defaultdict(lambda: MyClass)` and `defaultdict(MyClass)`?

Comment: `lambda: MyClass` is basically a function that takes no arguments that `return MyClass`, which literally returns the `MyClass` class definition.

Comment: Can you explain why the statement `mydict['foo'].value = 1` works when I use `defaultdict(lambda: MyClass)`? According to your argument, the member variable `value` should not exist if I use `lambda`.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 if you read the traceback and the exception message that you posted in your question you would have know the answer already... regardless I updated the answer just for you to be exceptionally clear.

Comment: I did indeed read the traceback but didn't understand the problem; that is why I'm posting to Stackoverflow. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: More that `type object 'MyClass' has no attribute 'value'` clearly states that lack of the `value` attribute on the `MyClass` and from the statement `mydict['foo'].value` clearly shows that `.value` of `mydict['foo']` means `mydict['foo']` produced `MyClass`.  You can always try to execute one fragment of a statement at a time (i.e. `print(mydict['foo'])` to see what it produced).